# Can I set the node option --max-old-space-size in angular project?

Tags: node.js, angular

How to set different --max-old-space-size to different angular project.

I meet Heap Out of Memory Error in my angular cil project, I set a node_option --max-old-space-size environment variable solve this error successfully. But I want to set different --max-old-space-size to different angular project.I find the most common answer is add it into the package.json or npx command but it is not fit to my project case. Is any other method to do it?

Comment: I think you could add it to NODE_OPTIONS environmental variable

Comment: This is how I solve this problem now. The new problem is environment variable is working on all my angular project, but I want different angular project has different --max-old-space-size setting.

Comment: If you are using zsh shell, you can try the dotenv https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/dotenv plugin, it can load .env file when you `cd` into a directory so that you can store the node options in `.env` files for different projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use following command when you build angular projects

```
node --max-old-space-size=2048 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod
```

you can run above command for different angular projects. max-old-space-size=2048 is for example. you can use your choice of size.